# Custom validator message not displaying

Tags: asp.net, validation, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, visual-studio-2013

- VS2013, WebForms, .NET 4.51

I have a FormView defined and in my EditTemplate I have as follows:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label ID="lblClientClassification" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" runat="server" for="cblClientClassifications" Text="Kind"></asp:Label>
     <div class="col-md-5">
         <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblClientClassifications" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
         <asp:CustomValidator ID="cfvClientKinds" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="label label-danger" ErrorMessage="XXXX" ValidationGroup="Default" OnServerValidate="cfvClientClassifications_OnServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
 </div>
```

and then in the code behind:

```
    protected void cfvClientClassifications_OnServerValidate(object aSource, ServerValidateEventArgs aArgs)
    {
        CustomValidator cvCheckBoxKinds = aSource as CustomValidator;
        int checkedCount = 0;
        if (cvCheckBoxKinds != null)
        {
            CheckBoxList cblClientClassifications = GuiClientClassificationsFind();
            foreach (ListItem listItem in cblClientClassifications.Items)
            {
                if (listItem.Selected)
                {
                    checkedCount++;
                }
            }

            if (checkedCount == 0)
            {
                aArgs.IsValid = false;
                cvCheckBoxKinds.ErrorMessage = "Select client kind.";
            }
        }
    }
```

The OnServerValidate is firing and I am getting to set the validator to invalid as well as setting the error message (Page.IsValid is also false as expected). However, the error text is not displaying. When I view the page source I see:

```
<span id="ctl00_cphMainContent_fvData_cfvClientKinds" class="label label-danger" style="display:none;">XXXX</span>
```

instead of the error message I set as well as the fact that it is not visible.

Has anyone got any pointers here on how to track this down? I have looked at similar questions of SO but none of the comments seem to apply. Is this related to FormView perhaps?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this?

Comment: Nope, never did solve this one.

Comment: I have solved my issue soon after I asked you. I'm sharing my code below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try your control without the CssClass="label label-danger" bootstrap first, and use the code below to check your boxes:

```
    protected void cfvClientKinds_ServerValidate(object aSource, ServerValidateEventArgs aArgs)
    {
        aArgs.IsValid = cblClientClassifications.SelectedItem != null;
        cfvClientKinds.ErrorMessage = "Hey! this is a new message";
    }
```

and I guess you call this line before you fire the above event:

```
    protected void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Short, I think that your problem is either related to your way of finding `cblClientClassifications` checkBoxList or other code that you haven't stated above.

```
CheckBoxList cblClientClassifications = GuiClientClassificationsFind();
```

I decided to try out your case and created a new webform added formview and bind it to northwind categories table then inside edititemtemplate I added a checkboxlist and populated it manually. added CustomValidator double clicked it copied your codebehind and it works for me except for the findcontrol part: `GuiClientClassificationsFind();` 
Here is the formview:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CategoryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblClientClassifications" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Bir</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>iki</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Üç</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Dört</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cfvClientKinds" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="label label-danger" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" OnServerValidate="cfvClientKinds_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

And codebehind with your code:

```
protected void cfvClientKinds_ServerValidate(object aSource, ServerValidateEventArgs aArgs)
        {
            CustomValidator cvCheckBoxKinds = aSource as CustomValidator;
            CheckBoxList cblClientClassifications = (CheckBoxList)FormView1.FindControl("cblClientClassifications");
            int checkedCount = 0;
            if (cvCheckBoxKinds != null)
            {
                foreach (ListItem listItem in cblClientClassifications.Items)
                {
                    if (listItem.Selected)
                    {
                        checkedCount++;
                    }
                }

                if (checkedCount == 0)
                {
                    aArgs.IsValid = false;
                    cvCheckBoxKinds.ErrorMessage = "Select client kind.";
                }
            }
        }
```

I Ali Shahrokhi's method is shorter and works as well as yours..

```
protected void cfvClientKinds_ServerValidate(object aSource, ServerValidateEventArgs aArgs)
        {
            CustomValidator cvCheckBoxKinds = aSource as CustomValidator;
            CheckBoxList cblClientClassifications = (CheckBoxList)FormView1.FindControl("cblClientClassifications");
            aArgs.IsValid = cblClientClassifications.SelectedItem != null;
            cvCheckBoxKinds.ErrorMessage = "Select client kind.";
        }
```

if you check as you entered edititemtemplate in formview you'll see before submitting that your customvalidators `span` will be there just as you mentioned that's because server hasn't sent it to the client yet somehow.